# BTreeMap storage type

Tags: polkadot, storage, frame, runtime, btreemap

I would like to store a large amount of sorted integers, they should be traversable with efficient `get` and `insert`.

If I can iterate over a storage map, could you let me know how?

Or is there a BTreeMap storage type?

Comment: As a ballpark estimate, if you would have a sorted array of all those integers, how much memory would that consume?

Comment: I would have a look at staking's use of bags list. It's not a perfect sort: the bags represent ranges of values. Off-chain sorting can be done and then the results posted on chain. https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_bags_list/index.html

Answer (score 6):

There is no sorted storage type. That would be way too expensive to realize, just imagine adding an item how many storage reads that would need. However, for small things you can just use a storage value that uses a `BTreeMap` as type. Here you just need to be aware that every time you access it, you would need to decode the entire `BTreeMap`. In the end it boils down to what you want to achieve and what are your constraints.

Comment: And please also pay attention to the constant cost of such advanced data structure. If the size of the container is not larger than some amount (e.g. 30-50), a naive vector can be even more efficient.